# WebRequest crashes in IPv6 network (XAMARIN)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, webrequest

Two day ago I sent my app to Apple in order to get it approved in the AppStore.

However today they answered me and told me that my app crashes in an IPv6 Network when trying to login. Unfortunately I'm not able to create an IPv6 network at my workplace in order to debug the app and see whats causing the crash.

I'm using the WebRequest class to connect and in our own IPv4 network I encountered no crashes yet trying to establish a connection.

Have any of you encountered this situation and if so how did you resolve the problem?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did you ever solve that problem? I am also having issues with WebRequest in ipv6 networks. Leads to ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network is unreachable

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502766/why-is-my-webrequest-in-xamarin-ios-failing-in-ipv6-environment